# Voisin's proof of Ehresmann's theorem

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

On p.221 of Voisin's book on Hodge theory, there are two claims:

a) Let $B$ be a contractible smooth manifold. There exists a vector field $\chi$ on $B$ whose flow $\Phi_t$ is global and, given any neighborhood $U$ of the point we contract to, we can find $T$ such that, for all $t \geq T$, $Im_t$ is contained in $U$.

b) Let $B$ and $X$ be smooth manifolds, $\chi$ a global vector field on $B$, $\phi: X \rightarrow B$ a submersion [WAS MISSING, NOW ADDED] which is smooth and proper. Then $\chi$ lifts to a global vector field $\chi'$ on $X$. [as now stated see 
[Need help understanding a lift of a vector field](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/143440/need-help-understanding-a-lift-of-a-vector-field) ]
How do we prove these?

Comment: Statement (b) is false. For example, let $B = X = \mathbb R$, and let $\phi\colon X\to B$ be $\phi(x) = x^3$.  Then $\phi$ is smooth, and it's proper because it's a homeomorphism. But the vector field $\partial/\partial x$ has no lift to $X$.

Comment: @JackLee It would be great to have that as an answer instead of a comment. Deserves more visibility than it has right now.

Comment: @Mark, I think it would be better to give the OP an opportunity to modify the question.  I think he's missing a hypothesis in (b).  (And besides, I don't have any idea how to answer question (a).)

Comment: I think in (b) should be a smooth proper submersion. But in the sense of algebraic geometry, a smooth morphism would also be a submersion, so….

Comment: OK, now (b) makes sense.  The hint given in the last comment to the question you linked to should help: Locally you can find coordinates in which $\phi$ has the form $(x^1,\dots,x^k,x^{k+1},\dots,x^n)\mapsto (x^1,\dots,x^k)$, and in these coordinates, finding a smooth local lift is easy. Then patch together with a partition of unity. But I still don't know how to do part (a).